# Python - pass a variable/object as argument to be used in a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm still learning, so please forgive me if my fundamental idea of how this works is way off.

Anyways, I have two python programs. Program 1 functions to connect to a db and run a query. I would like to be able to pass a variable from program 2 to be used within a function in program 1... like this (note the * portion of the update query):

```
def updateSent():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPassword+';DSN='+dbHost)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    update_stmt = "UPDATE WKM_sms_outbound SET status = 'sent' WHERE msg_id = ****VALUE FROM msgId****"
    cursor.execute(update_stmt)
```

and be able to call it like this from the other program:

```
updateSent(msgId)
```

I've searched around but I don't think i'm close enough with my wording to find what I'm looking for. 
Thank you ahead of time.

EDIT: here's the full code for both of the modules.

```
import pyodbc

# declare creds to login to db
dbUser="dba"
dbPassword="sql"
dbHost="Needles"
dbPort="2638"
dbConnection=None

# function to fetch/return latest sms from needles db
def pullData():
    # connect
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPassword+';DSN='+dbHost)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    # run query & store to dictionary
    outbound = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM WKM_SMS_outbound ORDER BY id DESC")
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    collection = {}
    for index, outbound in enumerate(results):
        key_name = "col{0}".format(index)
        collection[key_name] = outbound

    # store desired keys/values to vars
    msg = collection['col1']
    destPhone = collection['col2']
    msgId = collection['col3']
    caseNum = collection['col4']
    sender = collection['col10']

    # close connection
    cnxn.close()

    # return desired fields for sending
    return (msg, destPhone, msgId, caseNum, sender)

def updateSent():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPassword+';DSN='+dbHost)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    update_stmt = "UPDATE WKM_sms_outbound SET status = 'sent' WHERE msg_id = *********"
    cursor.execute(update_stmt)
```

And the other module:

```
import requests
from otherModule import pullData
from otherModule import updateSent
from datetime import datetime
from Logger import Logger

# call function from other module to pull sms
msg, destPhone, msgId, caseNum, sender = pullData()

# declare vars
msg=msg
destPhone=destPhone
sender=sender
msgId=str(msgId)

# headers and parameters required for api
headers = {
    'x-api-token': '1130FxmIcc****oCZZPCpq8ODQo',
    'x-api-key': 'pdwz0naW5hyC****nOf26BZFS28',
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---'
}

formData = {
    'locationId': '2045',
    'messageBody': msg,
    'contactPhone': destPhone
}

# POST & log the sms request
Logger.writeAndPrintLine('[REQ: ' + msgId + '] ' + sender + ' to ' + destPhone, 1)

updateSent(msgId)

r=requests.post('https://api.***.com/v1/conversations/messages', headers=headers, params=formData).text
```

Comment: You need to import `msgId` from the other module. It's not possible to help with what you've given

Comment: import program1 file into program2 file and use function

Comment: `updateSent` needs to be defined to take at least one parameter (and `dbUser` et al. should also be passed as parameters, rather than assumed to be global variables).

Comment: Also, `update_stmt = "UPDATE ... WHERE msg_id = %s"`, then `cursor.execute(update_stmt, (msg_id,))`. `pyodbc` may use a different placeholder than `%s` for parameterized queries; consult the documentation.

Comment: Do you really have separate programs or just separate modules?

Comment: Are you actually running two different *programs*, i.e. two different processes? Or do you just have two different `.py` files?

Comment: Separate modules... I believe to be the correct terminology (two different .py files). msgId already is imported from the other module... I suppose I just don't know how to code the updateSent() function to pass in the variable where I need it in the sql query.

Comment: I added the full code for both modules for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
def updateSent(MsgIdValue):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('UID='+dbUser+';PWD='+dbPassword+';DSN='+dbHost)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    update_stmt = "UPDATE WKM_sms_outbound SET status = 'sent' WHERE msg_id = " + str(MsgIdValue)
    cursor.execute(update_stmt)
```

The point is to have the value MsgIdValue as a parameter to the function. Your query string needs this value, here by adding a string version of your value.

Edit: you seem to have more than one question. This only addresses one part of the question

Comment: Thank you for this- it was accurate in regards to python, and my program runs without error. However, it does not make the update in the db. It's odd because I added a line to print str(msgId) to the updateSent() function, and it prints the correct value, so that's all working, but it seems the query simply isn't running at all.

Comment: oops- i didn't commit()